# Python Syntax Error on Data Cast in R Script Issue

Tags: python, r, casting

I'm attempting to run an R script from python. I can see it's executing, but python is erroring out on a syntax error for the R script. The R script runs fine in RStudio, so I'm not sure what the issue might be. Any suggestions would be helpful.

This is my python code:

```
import sys
import subprocess

# other stuff going on

# execute R script which returns a document in a directory
subprocess.call([sys.executable, "C:/Users/path/sentiment_extraction.r"])

sentiment = pd.read_csv("new_sentiment_data.csv")
```

And here is my R script:

```
#! /usr/bin/Rscript
require(syuzhet)

today_news <- read.csv("C:/Users/path/Today_News.csv")  # created from above python script

#Sentiments words table:
records <- as.character(today_news$News)
sentiment <- get_nrc_sentiment(records)

# other stuff that makes a file
```

Then this is the Python error I get:

> File "C:/Users/path/sentiment_extraction.r", line 7
>
> ```
> records <- as.character(today_news$News)
>              ^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

The data I use syuzhet on needs to be a character vector so I cast the column.

Comment: Can you try to print the `str(today_news)`

Comment: today_news is a file. When I do today_news$News, that's R for taking the data in just the column 'News" in the file today_news...

Comment: I understand that part.  It is to check whether there is anything different with `str(today_news)` using this approach and while reading directly on R

Comment: In the python script there is no today_news object. So if I do `print(str(today_news))` it would print nothing. I create the file by doing this: `master_df.to_csv('Today_News.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False, sep=',')` Do you want to see the data in the file?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My parameters to run the R file were incorrect. I had to pass the path to Rscript.exe:

`subprocess.call(["C:/Users/seeme/Documents/R/R-3.4.0/bin/Rscript",
                 "C:/Users/path/sentiment_extraction.r"])`